# Is this partially ordered set?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, asymptotics, relations, order-theory

We have set $X$ consisting of positive functions $f: \Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{R}^+$. Are the following relations partial order sets?

1) $f(n)Rg(n) ⇔ f(n) = o\big(g(n)\big)$

2) $f(n)Sg(n) ⇔ f(n) = O\big(g(n)\big)$

3) $f(n)Tg(n) ⇔ f(n) = o\big(g(n)\big) ∨ f(n) = g(n) ∀ n ∈ \Bbb{N}$

I know that partially ordered set means the set is reflexive, transitive and antisymmetrical. But how do I check each one of this qualities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

Let's do this to $S$, for example.

- *reflexive* means (f,f) \in S. Is it true that $f(n) = O(g(n))$?
- *transitive* means that if $(f,g) \in S$ and $(g,h) \in S$ then $(f,h) \in S$. So if $f(n) = O(g(n))$ and $g(n) = O(h(n))$, can you say $f(n) = O(h(n))$?
- *antisymmetric* means if $(f,g) \in S$ and $(g,f) \in S$ then $f=g$. So if $f(n)=O(g(n))$ and $g(n) = O(f(n))$ then $f(n) = g(n)$?

Comment: The first and second are true. The third one is incorrect. Am I right?

Comment: @Mirek indeed, you are right. So what is the conclusion, is $S$ a partial order? Can you try the same approach for $R$ and $T$ in your problem?

Comment: Therefore it is not. RIght? I will try the same approach now. But I have additional question. In a way I can understand why these thing are true or not. For example in the third one, just because they have the same complexity as the other function, they don't necessarily have to be the same, but what is the mathematical way (low level) to prove these? Do I even have to elaborate on it?

Comment: @Mirek Right, $S$ is not a partial order. The level of detail for your proofs depends on the class, usually spelling it out is ok. Here, if a formal proof is required, it is easy to notice that $(f,g) \in S$ and $(g,f) \in S$ means $f = \Theta(g)$, which clearly does not mean $f=g$, since you can have, for example, $f(n) = n$ and $g(n) = 3n$. That's a counter-example.